# Google Code uploader script doesn't work out-of-the-box

Tags: python

I'm trying to run http://support.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/scripts/googlecode_upload.py .

It gives me this:

```
File "googlecode_upload.py", line 184
  print 'Please enter your googlecode.com password.'
                                                   ^
```

I'm quite new to Python, but that line doesn't seem to have anything out of the ordinary, so I'm baffled. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess: are you using Python 3? In Python 3, it would need to be:

```
print('Please enter your googlecode.com password.')
```

The script is written to be run in Python 2, so you may want to get 2.7. Python 3 is the up and coming thing in Python, but Python 2 is still more widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for Google AppEngine?  It wants Python 2.*5*

> The Python SDK includes a web server
>   application that simulates the App
>   Engine environment, including a local
>   version of the datastore, Google
>   Accounts, and the ability to fetch
>   URLs and send email directly from your
>   computer using the App Engine APIs.
>   The Python SDK runs on any computer
>   with Python 2.5, and versions are
>   available for Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux. (The Python SDK is not
>   compatible with Python 3.)

[source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html)

Comment: It isn't for the app engine - it's a general-use script for uploading Google Code binaries.

Comment: I wonder if the [Python 2 to 3 converter](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) would work on it.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd rather leave it untouched and glom another script onto it that also uses Python 2.7, like so: http://code.google.com/p/benfwaves/source/browse/trunk/binupload.py